# FileNotFoundError despite the target file being in the same folder as the code

Tags: python, audio, filenotfounderror

I am trying to play music in the background of my project whilst it is running. Despite the audio file being in the folder containing my Python code I still receive a FileNotFoundError. More specifically: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Below is the code relevant to my problem.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

def play_mp3(file_path):
    sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(file_path)
    repeated_sound = sound * -1
    play(repeated_sound)

MusicThread = threading.Thread(target=play_mp3,args=("Music.mp3",),daemon=True)

MusicThread.start()
```

I have tried refreshing, closing vscode, using the file path, and using an alternate file path to the same file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pydub from\_mp3 gives \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34196195/pydub-from-mp3-gives-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Note: Although I was able to find an appropriate duplicate target by searching for `AudioSegment.from_mp3` you should provide a proper [mre] when asking questions. To start with you should mention the package you are using since it is not something from the standard library. Also [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you for the feedback. I will make sure to keep that in mind if I find myself asking another question

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to open the file for reading first with `open(file_path)`. See:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

```py
def play_mp3(file_path):
    sf = open(file_path)
    sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(sf)
    repeated_sound = sound * -1
    play(repeated_sound)
```

Comment: Yes, @mohamed-elkalioby is correct in suggesting the use of the ablolute path. Reading further, it does appear that the `from_mp3()` method can take a path as well as a filelike object.

Comment: I tried this but this error box was thrown whilst I was debugging. Below. (I thought that I could use enter to create a newline)

Comment: Exception has occurred: UnicodeDecodeError
'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 188: character maps to <undefined>
  File "C:\Users\willw\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\Test copy.py", line 79, in play_mp3
    sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(sf)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 188: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Ok, hm. I don't know too much about codecs, but clearly charmap is having an issue with one of the bytes in the file you're reading. (Obvious, sorry.) As I understand it, charmap reads byte values as strings, then converts them to numerical values in binary. Can you read/play this mp3 file using other means? (e.g. a mp3 player app) If I'm off base here, I hope someone more knowledgeable will set us straight! :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to get the absolute path when dealing with files so you don't encounter this issue. You do this simply as follows

```
import os
main_path=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

so that we return you the directory name of your script.
so to reach your file

```
MusicThread = threading.Thread(target=play_mp3,args=(main_path + "/Music.mp3",),daemon=True)
```